# AXSelectedRows: Getting selected rows for AXOutline

Tags: applescript

I feel that AXSelectedRows has finally beaten me into submission :) After extensive research, I am stumped as to how to programmatically list the contents of AXSelectedRows; simply put, to get the selected rows of any given AXOutline.

It sounds trivial, but finding an answer has proven difficult - particularly due to the lack of online documentation (though I should probably buy a book!) Strangely, a lot of people just seem to want to programmatically select rows, instead of getting selected rows.

I am certainly close though. I have reached thus far:

```
set selectedRows to value of attribute "AXSelectedRows" of outline1
```

where `outline1` is set to an AXOutline. Next:

```
set selectedRow to item 1 of selectedRows
```

This is where it becomes a little murky (after already failing to set it to `row 1` instead of `item 1`). I would expect `selectedRow` to be of type `AXRow` (or `row`), but instead Automator output displays:

```
application "System Events"
```

That is, the item appears to be an instance of 'application "System Events"' - which leads me to believe that I'm overlooking something important. Having said that, I feel that I've tried every combination of `value`'s, `attribute`'s and `row`'s - including some type-casting.

The frustrating part is that I can actually see the contents of AXSelectedRows in the Accessibility Inspector! And so I know that it exists. As a workaround, I am using:

```
set selectedRows to selected of rows of outline1
```

However, this is certainly not preferable as I still have to loop through the entire array in order to find the 'true' values, which could have performance issues for very large lists.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess getting the value of AXSelectedRows is just something that has not been implemented. When I open a Finder window in list view, select two rows, and run this script:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell window 1 of process "Finder"
    value of attribute "AXSelectedRows" of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1
end tell
```

The result is:

```
{application "System Events", application "System Events"}
```

However you can use a whose clause to get the selected rows without using a repeat loop:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    rows of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1 where selected is true
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you for investigating this, Lri. Your suggestion works a treat!...while also being efficient. I'd be surprised if it has not been implemented though - I believe it is more likely to be a bug in AppleScript. According to Apple's own documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXRoleConstants_header_reference/Reference/reference.html), AXSelectedRows should return an array - and therefore the bug would be that they forgot to implement it :) Either way, you've satisfactorily answered the question!